# Under what license is the Stack Exchange blog source released?

Tags: discussion, support, licensing

Under what license is the [Stack Exchange blog](https://blog.stackexchange.com/#page1) [source](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog) released?

The Stack Exchange repository (not the forked) does not specify any specific license.

> In short - Can I use some (or all) parts of it for my own blog. Without worrying about legal issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The repository does not specify any specific license.

It does, in the [LICENSE file](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/blob/master/LICENSE). It's released under the MIT license, so outside of being mindful of [the copyright guideance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) you shouldn't have any issue.

Comment: Just confirming - so what [Barry](https://github.com/barryclark) written in that [license](https://github.com/StackExchange/blog/blob/master/LICENSE) applies to this repository also. Right?

Comment: Yes, the license is applicable for the whole repository.